# Couldn't able to build node-gyp Visual Studio 2013 support

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, node-sqlserver

I'm using Visual Studio 2013, and i need to do a example project with [msnodesql](https://www.npmjs.org/package/msnodesql), I  installed [node-gyp](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-gyp) globally, then i tried to configure the node-gyp using `node-gyp configure` command, it executed successfully, but when i tried to build the node-gyp using `node-gyp build`. It shows me so many errors.

I also updated `MSVSVersion.py` as suggested in this [link](https://code.google.com/p/gyp/source/detail?spec=svn1763&r=1725) but no use.

I get several errors like `error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int  OdbcOperation.h`.

```
error C2819: type 'mssql::OdbcOperation' does not have an overloaded member 'operator -> OdbcOperation.cpp'
```

Could any one help me with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the node-gyp GitHub page the [installation](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp#installation) details list the prerequisites for installing on windows.

Basically you need either VS2010 or 2012 installed (depending on OS) and if on Windows 7 the Windows 7 sdk.

Comment: I successfully compiled [node-odbc](http://github.com/wankdanker/node-odbc) with VS 2013 on Windows 8.1 64bit, but I had to do some manual changes between `configure` and `build`: Open *.sln and upgrade to VS12, save, manually checkout/install dependencies (since `npm install` will fail because it will auto-run gyp, which fails because it requires VS10), build, copy `*.node` to folder where Node.js can find it. No Windows SDK, unless it comes with VS12?! Maybe that helps. Still seeking for a way to let gyp generate a VS12 solution...